# Python Build Error: fatal error: misc/abstract_atomic.h: No such file or directory

Tags: compilation, python-2.6, linux-mint-21

Im using Linux Mint 21 and I'm trying to build python 2.6.2 I need it for Blender 2.49b. So here is error which Im getting

```
from /home/slobodan/Python-2.6.2/Modules/nismodule.c:17:
/usr/include/rpc/types.h:189:10: fatal error: misc/abstract_atomic.h: No such file or directory
  189 | #include <misc/abstract_atomic.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

I have installed `libntirpc-dev` and I tried to tell make where my `ntirpc` is like [suggested here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1360089/rpc-h-missing-ubuntu-21-04/1360094#comment2330542_1360094) `make CFLAGS=-I/usr/include/ntirpc` so it did find `#include <rpc/rpc.h>` but it cant find
`<misc/abstract_atomic.h>`but I have it on my system

```
apt-file search misc/abstract_atomic.h
libntirpc-dev: /usr/include/ntirpc/misc/abstract_atomic.h
```

and make cant find it on my system so what Im doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

So eventually I needed to symbolic link files so C preprocessor can find them, here is whole list, but first `apt install libntirpc-dev`

```
sudo ln -s /usr/include/ntirpc/rpc/rpc.h /usr/include/rpc
sudo ln -s /usr/include/ntirpc/misc/abstract_atomic.h /usr/include/misc/
sudo ln -s /usr/include/ntirpc/netconfig.h /usr/include/misc/
sudo ln -s /usr/include/ntirpc/misc/stdio.h /usr/include/misc
sudo ln -s /usr/include/ntirpc/intrinsic.h /usr/include
sudo ln -s /usr/include/ntirpc/rpc/tirpc_compat.h /usr/include/rpc
sudo ln -s /usr/include/ntirpc/rpc/auth.h /usr/include/rpc
sudo ln -s /usr/include/ntirpc/rpc/rpc_err.h /usr/include/rpc
sudo ln -s /usr/include/ntirpc/rpc/clnt_stat.h /usr/include/rpc
sudo ln -s /usr/include/ntirpc/rpc/auth_stat.h /usr/include/rpc
sudo ln -s /usr/include/ntirpc/rpc/clnt.h /usr/include/rpc
sudo ln -s /usr/include/ntirpc/misc/rbtree.h /usr/include/misc
sudo ln -s /usr/include/ntirpc/misc/opr.h /usr/include/misc
sudo ln -s /usr/include/ntirpc/misc/wait_queue.h /usr/include/misc
sudo ln -s /usr/include/ntirpc/misc/queue.h /usr/include/misc
sudo ln -s /usr/include/ntirpc/reentrant.h /usr/include
sudo ln -s /usr/include/ntirpc/rpc/svc.h /usr/include/rpc
sudo ln -s /usr/include/ntirpc/rpc/rpc_msg.h /usr/include/rpc
sudo ln -s /usr/include/ntirpc/rpc/work_pool.h /usr/include/rpc
sudo ln -s /usr/include/ntirpc/rpc/pool_queue.h /usr/include/rpc
sudo ln -s /usr/include/ntirpc/misc/portable.h /usr/include/misc
sudo ln -s /usr/include/ntirpc/misc/timespec.h /usr/include/misc
sudo ln -s /usr/include/ntirpc/misc/os_epoll.h /usr/include/misc
sudo ln -s /usr/include/ntirpc/rpc/auth_unix.h /usr/include/rpc
sudo ln -s /usr/include/ntirpc/rpc/rpcb_clnt.h /usr/include/rpc
sudo ln -s /usr/include/ntirpc/rpc/rpcb_prot.h /usr/include/rpc
sudo ln -s /usr/include/ntirpc/rpc/rpcent.h /usr/include/rpc
```